# Identify my network printer in serial port

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, cups-lpd

I have a Zebra printer that works fine in my network, all fine with CUPS install.

Now, I have a legacy software that prints only on serial ports, so I need to create - in some way - a redirect from my serial port to my network printer.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and the printer was found and working well with the Zebra ZPL printer.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A couple easy methods: https://superuser.com/questions/614494/redirect-serial-com-to-tcp-port

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this would work, but you can buy Moxa equipment (another type is Digiport), that acts as an IP-to-serial converter and could potentially use that to get you going.

Moxa https://www.moxa.com/en/products/industrial-edge-connectivity/serial-device-servers

Digiport Portserver https://www.digi.com/products/networking/infrastructure-management/serial-connectivity/serial-device-servers/portserverts